# How to pre-populate android room database with Rxjava

Tags: java, android, rx-java2, android-room, populate

How do I properly pre-populate my database using Rxjava

Here is my dao

```
@Query("SELECT * from questions WHERE difficulty  = :difficulty")
Flowable<List<Question>> getQuestions(String difficulty);

// Emits the number of users added to the database.
@Insert
public Maybe<long[]> insertQuestions(List<Question> questions);
```

Here is my database class

```
    public static synchronized QuestionDatabase getInstance(Context context) {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(), QuestionDatabase.class, "questions_database")
                .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                //.addMigrations(MIGRATION_1_2)
                .addCallback(roomCallback)
                .build();
    }
    return instance;
}

private static RoomDatabase.Callback roomCallback = new RoomDatabase.Callback() {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
        super.onCreate(db);

        QuestionDao questionDao = instance.questionDao();

        List<Question> questions = new ArrayList<>();

        questions.add(new Question("A is correct", "A", "B", "C", 1, GameConstants.DIFFICULTY_EASY));
        questions.add(new Question("C is correct", "A", "B", "C", 3, GameConstants.DIFFICULTY_HARD));
        questions.add(new Question("B is correct", "A", "B", "C", 2, GameConstants.DIFFICULTY_EASY));

        //inserting records
        questionDao.insertQuestions(questions)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                //.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(
                        new Consumer<long[]>() {

                            @Override
                            public void accept(long[] longs) throws Exception {

                            }
                        },
                        new Consumer<Throwable>() {
                            @Override
                            public void accept(Throwable throwable) throws Exception {

                            }
                        });


    }
};
```

The problem that I am having is the following:

the database is only populated when I call a method on an activity p.Ex:

```
        //getting flowable to subscribe consumer that will access the data from Room database.
    questionDao.getQuestions(GameConstants.DIFFICULTY_HARD)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(
            new Consumer<List<Question>>() {
                @Override
                public void accept(List<Question> questions) throws Exception {

                    questionList = (ArrayList<Question>)questions;
                    questionCountTotal = questionList.size();
                    Collections.shuffle(questionList);
                    showNextQuestion();
                }
            },
            new Consumer<Throwable>() {
                @Override
                public void accept(Throwable throwable) throws Exception {

                }
            }
    );
```

And when I call this method I get the questions twice. I check this by putting a break point inside the accept method of questionDao.getQuestions. 
I believe two threads are running one to populate and a second one to get the questions.

Why is this happening and how do I implement this the proper way?

Thanks in advance

Comment: From where you call the `getQuestions`?

Comment: I call it from the main activity

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the following changes will work

1. Change the **getInstance** method to force open the database, thus causing **onCreate** to run when you get the instance rather than not until you attempt to access the database.

as per (see comment):-

```
public static synchronized QuestionDatabase getInstance(Context context) {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(), QuestionDatabase.class, "questions_database")
                .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                //.addMigrations(MIGRATION_1_2)
                .addCallback(roomCallback)
                .build();
    }
    instance.getOpenHelper().getWritableDatabase(); //<<<<<<<<<< Forces an Open thus creation of the Database
    return instance;
}
```

2. Add the initial questions without subscribing

i.e. instead of

```
    //inserting records
    questionDao.insertQuestions(questions)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            //.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(
                    new Consumer<long[]>() {

                        @Override
                        public void accept(long[] longs) throws Exception {

                        }
                    },
                    new Consumer<Throwable>() {
                        @Override
                        public void accept(Throwable throwable) throws Exception {

                        }
                    });
```

Just use :-

```
    questionDao.insertQuestions(questions);
```

When you get the instance back in the activity the database will be populated.

Comment: I tried your solution but Its not working. If I dont subscribe  `questionDao.insertQuestions(questions)` the questions are not saved in the database